# Can't connect to wired network

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.10

Just installed Ubuntu 16.10 and can't connect to wired network, for some reason my PC doesn't even try to connect.

```
0a:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57762 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev ff)
```

Comment: Please post the Ethernet device, not the wireless.

Comment: 0a:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57762 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev ff)

Comment: it happened right after i installed system updates, before it wired connection was ok

Comment: Can you go to recovery mode and select a previous kernel version?

Comment: What's the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Ethernet`?

Comment: Very strange behavior of my mac,  now i have wired connection, but if i close the lid and suspend mac it wakes up with wired connection icon, but without any internet connection :|

Comment: lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Ethernet
0a:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Limited NetXtreme BCM57762 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1682]
 Subsystem: Apple Inc. NetXtreme BCM57762 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [106b:00f6]
 Kernel driver in use: tg3
 Kernel modules: tg3